# PySpark from_json Schema for ArrayType with No Name

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to use from_json with the following JSON string and need to specify a schema. What schema matches this JSON?

```
[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]
```

As a work-around, I'm doing a string concat to turn the JSON into this (i.e. adding an array name).

```
{ "data": [{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}] }
```

Then I can use the following schema. However, it should be possible to specify a schema without changing the original JSON.

```
schema = StructType([
  StructField("data", ArrayType(
    StructType([
      StructField("key", StringType())
    ])
  ))
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Here is the example

```py
df = self.spark.createDataFrame(['[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]'], StringType())
df.show(1, False)

schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField("key", StringType(), True)]))

df = df.withColumn("json", from_json("value", schema))
df.show()

+--------------------------------------+
|value                                 |
+--------------------------------------+
|[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]|
+--------------------------------------+

+--------------------+--------------------+
|               value|                json|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[{"key": "value1"...|[[value1], [value2]]|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```